# Responsive content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Guys can you help me with some explication?
I have the following code and I don't understand why the h element stretch into the width I set and the li element won't.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    ul li,h1{
      width:20px;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<ul>
<li>fffffffffffffffffffaaaaaaa</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I've attached an image and I wont the content to be inside the black border and stretch down like a block element but I won't happen.
[image]

Comment: can you please do it in jsfiddle?

Comment: if you want it to wrap around the containing element you shouldn't set any fixed value for the width. If you want the width to be of some value make sure it is smaller than the containing parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use word-warp:

```
ul li,h1{
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to wrap around the containing element you shouldn't set any fixed value for the width. If you want the width to be of some value make sure it is smaller than the containing parent.

Answer (score 0):

If content has no space then it will not wrap around the box. Use `word-wrap: break-word;` or `word-break: break-word;` to wrap content around the box.
see DEMO - https://jsfiddle.net/44njsodd/1/

```
ul li {

    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;

}
```